# What is the difference between "make" and "make all"?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile with the following structure (working example).

```
.PHONY: image flashcard put-files

put-files:
    @echo "=== put-files"

image:
    @echo "=== image"

flashcard:
    @echo "=== flashcard"

all: put-files image flashcard
    @echo "Done"
```

I expect that a simple `make` would build all three targets, but this is not so:

```
% make
=== put-files
```

But if I explicitly specify the target, the dependencies are built as well:

```
% make all
=== put-files
=== image
=== flashcard
Done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A simple `make` will build the first target in the list, which is `put-files`.

`make all` will build the target `all`. If you want `all` to be the default, then move it to the top of the list.

To understand what the `.PHONY` does, see http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Phony-Targets.html

Comment: You're right, my problem was that I somehow figured that the default target is chosen by name ("all"), instead of by position. Thanks a lot!